# How can I set a variable as a `table` in a procedure?

Tags: mysql, select

Table `t2` has 2 columns (id, tablename) with these values (1,2,3) x (toto, titi, tata):

```
id|tablename|
1 |toto|
2 |tata|
3 |titi|
```

I'd like to create a procedure which has id as a user-variable input and does this:

```
BEGIN 

 CREATE TABLE `newtable` AS (
 SELECT * FROM (SELECT tablename from t2 WHERE id=2); 
     );
END
```

The results should act as if the query was:

```
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE `newtable` AS (
SELECT * FROM `tata`
);
 END
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Just want to create a table with selecting data from an existing table? Why you can't set the user-defined variable inside the procedure only? Your create table syntax would be wrong based on this variable

Comment: Posting answer for the same, please verify.

Comment: Thanks for the updated comment & post, will provide an update for the same.

Comment: if answer does help, do upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `pr_create_table_by_reference`(
    IN `str_new_table_name` VARCHAR(50),
    IN `int_id` INT

)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN

    DECLARE STR_TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(1000) DEFAULT NULL;

    SELECT tablename INTO STR_TABLE_NAME FROM t2 WHERE id = int_id LIMIT 1;

    SET @prep_stmt = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE ', str_new_table_name ,' as ( SELECT * FROM ',  STR_TABLE_NAME , ')');

    PREPARE stmt FROM @prep_stmt; 
    EXECUTE stmt; 
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END

$$
```

**Procedure Call**:

```
SET @new_table:= 'newTable';
SET @id:= 2;
CALL `pr_create_table_by_reference`(@new_table, @id);

OR 

CALL `pr_create_table_by_reference`('newTable', 2);
```

Comment: id should be a user-variable input, not `newtable`

Comment: Just saw the updated question, much clear now, will provide an update soon.

Comment: you can see this one too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57650882/issue-with-complex-mysql-query-using-prepared-statement

Comment: Let me check this one too.